# Issue with Codeigniter Pagination And Search

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-routing

I am trying to give facility of **pagination and search keyword** in one report with Code-igniter Framework.

**Below is the Controller code for that Purpose:**

```
$queryString="?start_date=".$values['start_date']."&end_date=".$values['start_date']."&keyword=".$values['keyword']."";
    if($this->uri->segment(3)){
      $offset=$this->uri->segment(3);   
       $config['base_url'] = base_url()."reports/mysearch_search/".$offset.$queryString;                    
    }else{
       $config['base_url'] = base_url()."reports/mysearch_search/".$queryString;
    }
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM (`dlrReport`) WHERE LEFT(`res_submit_date`,10) >= '".$values['start_date']."' AND LEFT(`res_submit_date`,10) <= '".$values['end_date']."' AND (number LIKE '%".$values['keyword']."%' OR source LIKE '%".$values['keyword']."%')");            
    $config['total_rows']=$query->num_rows();            
    $config['per_page'] = 2;    
    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
    $where = array('LEFT(res_submit_date,10) >=' =>   $values['start_date'],'LEFT(res_submit_date,10) <=' =>$values['end_date']);
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->where("(number LIKE '%".$values['keyword']."%' OR source LIKE '%".$values['keyword']."%')");
    $res = $this->db->get('dlrReport', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
    $dlr['details']= $res->result();    
    $dlr['start_date']=$values['start_date'];   
    $dlr['end_date']=$values['end_date'];   
    $dlr['keyword']=$values['keyword'];         
    $this->load->view('mysearch',$dlr);
```

Getting Below link in pagination links which is not working:

```
http://Host/project/reports/mysearch_search/?start_date=2014-01-23&end_date=2014-01-23&keyword=/2
```

**Url i am expecting in pagination links is like:**

```
http://Host/project/reports/mysearch_search/2?start_date=2014-01-23&end_date=2014-01-23&keyword=
```

How can i will Get right Url for searching Purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Here is nice example from codeignter itself. [Codeigniter Pagination](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html) check this.

By default codeigniter is expecting the pagination url like this.

```
http://localhost/project/reports/mysearch_search/2014-01-23/2014-01-23/2

$start_date =$this->uri->segment(5);  
$end_date = $this->uri->segment(6);  
$keyword = $this->uri->segment(7);
```

and if you need this kind of url then you have to change the

```
http://example.com/index.php?c=test&m=page&per_page=20
```

then you have to change to set this on config  file

$config['enable_query_strings'] set to TRUE